# Error: unknown command 'gfxmode'. Pressing any key continues 

Tags: grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error on boot: unknown command 'gfxmode'. Pressing any key continues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131288/error-on-boot-unknown-command-gfxmode-pressing-any-key-continues)

A few days ago, I installed Ubuntu 12.04. I changed the order of systems on the list of boot loader
(I use Windows Vista and Ubuntu on one computer). I also changed, by the way, the appearance of the selection screen (resolution). All this with the Grub Customizer. After reboot and after the list of systems to choose was shown, I got a message: „**Error: unknown command 'gfxmode'. Pressing any key continues ...** ". Ubuntu starts even without pressing any key. The problem is repeated each time when I run Ubuntu. How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The grub customizer forgot to put `set` before gfxmode. Go into `/etc/grub.d` and run the following command to find out which file has the gfxmode entry: `grep gfxmode *` Then use whatever text editor you like to just put set in front of it.

A little background on this is that gfxmode is a variable, so it has to be set with the set command, but the customizer tried to use it as a command.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem deleting the line:

"gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode"

in "/etc/grub.d/40_custom" file

Answer (score 1):

I use [boot-repair](https://launchpad.net/boot-repair) software to reinstall the GRUB.

Then problem resolved.

You can see my comment on this bug.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/998835

Comment: Please do not repeat the same answer on different posts. If one answer can solve two questions, then the latest question is a duplicate of the first. In such a case, flag the question as a duplicate and we will handle the rest.

Comment: @Roland Taylor                                                 OK.I noticed.