# Error on boot: unknown command 'gfxmode'. Pressing any key continues

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, upgrade, grub2, updates

When I boot into Linux, I get this:

```
Error: unknown command 'gfxmode'. Pressing any key continues
```

It takes about 5 secs to boot after that.  Pretty slow compared to 11.10, I think. Anyway, my Ubuntu is 12.04 and it just updated today and changed the grub with grubcustomizer.  Anyway, I don't want any gfx interface or resolution on the grub customizer, but it keeps giving that error even if it isn't marked in grub customizer.

I found some help here, in this question: [Error: unknown command 'gfxmode'. Pressing any key continues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127327/error-unknown-command-gfxmode-pressing-any-key-continues)

I found the line it mentions in the `00_header`. But `Set` is found in front of the `gfx` there, so that isn't actually the problem.

This is my /etc/default/grub:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="1024x768x24"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"
```

Comment: Could you post your /etc/default/grub, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/linux` :

```
gksu gedit /etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/linux
```

Next, search for `gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode` in that file.

Comment out the line, with a `#` like(just in-case you need it):

`#gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode`

That will fix the problem but if you want to fix `gfxmode` Edit the line so that it says:

```
set gfxmode=\$linux_gfx_mode
```

Save the file.

- Note: there could be older script files in the same directory that
  also perpetuate the error. I made the above change, only to find grub
  was still balking on the "gfxmode" line. In the
  `/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts` dir I also found a file named
  "**linux~1**". Apparently, any script files in that dir get executed. In
  any case, when I edited the same line the same way in the "**linux~1**"
  file as well and updated grub, the problem went away. My guess is
  that "linux~1" is an older copy of the script and that I probably
  ought to have simply deleted it (or chmodded it non-executable).

Then you will need to update grub using the command:

```
 sudo update-grub
```

Comment: could you throw some info on what is the script for? and what am I removing if I delete the line?? and later If I change again any entry with grub customizer if it will happen again.? Thanks.

Comment: I have this: http://sharetext.org/DXZU   what of the 2 lines of the gfx mode do I delete??

Comment: your post solved it, thanks ^^, but Im worried about what it does...cant find any useful info.

Answer (score 1):

I use [boot-repair](https://launchpad.net/boot-repair) software to reinstall the GRUB.

Then the problem resolved.

You can see my comment on this bug.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/998835